# How to prevent Safari Technology Preview opening default Safari on launch?

Tags: safari, web-browser, macos

After selecting Safari Technology Preview as default browser it now also launches macOS's default version of Safari at the same time on launch. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This does not happen for me. Do you have any scripts bound to a web browser launching?

Comment: Thank you @BallpointBen - Is there somewhere to check? Turning Extensions off doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I have the same question, please someone help

Comment: Almost 2021 and I have the same question

Comment: 2021, same here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something to do with 1Password. [It's been reported on their forums and replicated by the support team](https://1password.community/discussion/108524/why-does-using-1password-on-safari-technology-preview-on-catalina-open-separate-safari-window).